# svn update is not updating!

Tags: svn

I want svn update to overwrite my local file with the files from the server, even if my local files have modifications, I want to throw them away and use the version that's on the remote repository.

How do I do that? I tried `svn update --force` but it doesn't work.

#### Update:

Thanks for the answers, so I'm using revert like this:

```
svn revert . -R
```

Is this how I'm supposed to use it? is it safe? I have a git repository in the same pace and I don't want svn to corrupt my `.git` for me!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use SVN revert. This would revert the files in your working copy to their original state. For more information and examples check the svn book here: 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re25.html

Comment: i thought it would be a good idea, so people could improve the answer. But now that i read the FAQ, it wont give me any reputation :( And I dont seem to be able to undo it :( Every day is a school day :)

Comment: ok, better luck next time hehe!! btw, what usually happens if someone has a better answer he will just post it and maybe refer to your answer if he wants to use it as a basis.

Comment: svn is ridiculous.  Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I just wanted to add a little to what diyism posted.

I didn't see the `.` next to the `;` in the line

```
svn revert -R .; svn up
```

and it confused me.  I don't know why you need to explicitly use `.` for all files when using **revert** and you don't using **update** but that seems to be the way it is.

So, in case it helps anyone, I thought it would be more clear to see the answer as two lines

```
svn revert -R .
svn update
```

Answer (score 5):

I have this problem occasionally on OSX (10.6, currently using svn 1.6.16). A workaround is to do this:

```
 svn update `svn ls -R`
```

It can be slow though.

Ref: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=3192

Comment: Maybe it's the same, I used `svn up --set-depth infinity`

Comment: **bash: /usr/local/bin/svn: Argument list too long**

Answer (score 4):

By the way, that's actually a feature of SVN. It will never overwrite any of your modifications when updating (unless you explicitly throw them away using `revert`.

Comment: And when subversion WON'T update, I have to throw my changes out with a REVERT to get rid of the wrinkle that has occurred between my working copy and Subversion server's folder versioning metadata system which is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Revert" instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to revert your modifications, and if necessary do an update after that.

Answer (score 2):

Use this line:

```
svn revert -R .;svn up
```

Answer (score 1):

use svn revert

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, delete the contents of your working copy (excluding the .svn folder) and do an update.