# Are server side folder renames (moves) known to create broken working copies in Subversion?

Tags: svn

[image]

I am encountering cases where subversion clients will not update using "svn update", and users have to wipe their working copies and check out fresh ones, or else like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840509/svn-update-is-not-updating)  they must revert first.

Why does this happen?  When it happens all the files that should have been clean/unmodified status, are shown as "added(+)", even though the user did not add them? The client side person has done nothing to render his working copy dirty. Changes have occurred on the server side, though,  on the server side, someone may have merged, comitted, then copied a branch from `/branches/featurebranch3/component/X` to  `/trunk/component/X`.

The developer who did NOT do this merge and merely has a working copy and is trying to track trunk and update every day, can not "update" his working copy, and must manually backup any uncommitted files, then either nuke the whole working copy, or do a `revert -R` then update again. When and why is this happening, and how is it related to server-side merges, moves and copies? I know the two are related, but I don't understand what is really happening.

If nobody ever did a folder move, delete or copy on the server then the incidence of this problem would be reduced.

I suspect server side rename/move could create a mixed revision situation but I don't know how.

One set of steps that may reliably reproduce this kind of broken working copy:

1. Create a folder `/branch/test1/components/component1`, do some merges and work INTO this branch.
2. Delete existing folder `/trunk/components/component1`
3. Copy folder `/branch/test1/components/component1` to  `/trunk/components/component1`
4. A REVERT is Not enough to fix this problem, it seems, one must erase the working copy and start over each time such a delete+copy is done on the server.
5. The message on the client during update is sometimes no error, just silent do nothing, and sometimes TortoiseSVN says "Skipped, no versioned parent" in the update, while files remain with status "normal(+)". This working copy can not be updated, nor reverted, and is stuck "in between".

Client: 1.8.5 SlikSvn or TortoiseSVN 1.8.5, build 25224.

SVNServer: 1.8.8

Comment: Could you narrow down the steps you use to cause the problem?

Comment: I use server side copies to create branches all the time, and occasional server-side moves. Never had a problem like this.

Comment: I am still trying to generate a Self Contained Example.  I am hoping someone has seen this and has already got an idea. Mixed working copies?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you gave the errors you're getting and the version of the Subversion clients in use.  Without the error messages it's hard to know what's actually happening.  Mixed revisions shouldn't cause any issue with a client update because the client reports the revisions it has and the server generates the actions to take to bring the client's working copy up to date with the requested revision.

Comment: There are no error messages. Updates that should be coming to the client machine merely do not ever make their way to the client machine, until you revert.  This indicates a mixed-copy revision situation, but it seems to me that the client is being told precisely NOTHING about the problems. Perhaps the person who did the merge needed to do something ugly to generate this break in continuity?

Comment: Okay weird. Sometimes you can see errors in TortoiseSVN clients, but not any error messages with command line (sliksvn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to give my own answer to this question in the hopes that it helps people.

1. When you replace folder objects with other objects that are new and replace the prior object, it appears there is no revision graph information linking the two folder objects. Thus, there is no possibility to track and update working copies that are based on the prior working folders.
2. Whereas "C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3" is the SAME object as far as YOU are concerned, it is NOT the same object in Subversion's terms. Subversion's job is to store objects in its databases (either SQLITE on the client side, or the FSFS store on the server) that can have infinitely many objects of the same exact name and even the same exact folder or effective fully qualified path name in YOUR WORKING COPY, and yet, never will it equate Folder3 the first with Folder3 the second. It is as a result of this intentional decision (to permit the storage of folders and making them the first class entity in SVN's system, rather than the content of your source code files, perhaps encoded as DIFF files, as you see in CVS and Mercurial, which do not track folders at all, and which can not generate equivalently broken working copies) that leads to working copies becoming effectively invalid and no longer updateable, which is the root of the problem I describe above.
3. The only consistent symptom of Subversion being completely broken is hundreds or thousands of **normal(+)** status indicators in TortoiseSVN.  The "skipped, no versioned parent" is not always emitted, but when it is output, that's a good sign you're borked too.
4. Some situations CAN be worked around by using SVN SWITCH and then SVN REVERT and then SVN UPDATE, but many can not.

So in short:

A. Don't do this. Don't replace objects. Because subversion can't handle it, and won't warn you, it just breaks all the users and breaks all their working copies.

B.  Subversion is not a file based version control system (like git, mercurial, and cvs), it's a container versioning system, and its containers look like folders until you actually try to merge, and then they are nothing like anything you could possibly imagine. Subversion versions containers which not only contain your files, and happen to look a lot like folders, they also are meta-data containers for all kinds of subversion's own versioning metadata, and there are LOTS of ways you can break the chain, and render your working copy invisibly broken. Git, Mercurial and CVS work with file content, which is what programmers care about.  Subversion versions folders and creates "tree conflicts", which is not useful to developers, since folders are only a way to organize source code, and are not (to a git developer's mind) owners of obscure invisible metadata. 
Subversion can not even speak up and tell you what's up, because the model is so broken no sensible error message in plain english could make it easy to tell how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Server-side merges (technically) is non-existing thing: merges always happen in WC and appear in repository as result of commit
2. If anybody use SVN in brainless non-mainline way, he'll get such exactly brainless result

If your test-case steps 2-3 are just delirium: all changes from branch must (by default) appear in source node as result of merge. If you want transfer into trunk exact full state of branch HEAD and overwrite all changes in thunk from the point of divergence - use `svn merge` with correct `--accept` option (probably 'theirs-full' will be safest type)

Comment: Let's assume the obvious here.  User does the merge in a working copy switched to that server's branch location as specified. Then commits. Now that change is merged "in that branch" on the server. I am, of course, aware of how SVN works.  Are you?  Can you explain why of course, "brainless results" ensue? I say Subversion is broken by design.